# Identity of SOT23-5 Lipo Battery Monitor IC

Tags: identification, components, lipo, battery-balance

Please can anyone help with identification of a sot 23-5 package marked GCLK in a single channel of a rechargeable lipo balance circuit
[image: part on circuit board]

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: It might help if you could supply specs for the balance device and perhaps a picture of the entire board and connections to the cells. Also, why do you need to identify the device? If there is a problem you might do better by asking for troubleshooting advice, which might also provide clues about the IC.

Comment: More information would be helpful.

Comment: Another board with simlar IC marking https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235446/how-does-a-battery-balance-and-protection-circuit-work

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I don't have any specs as trying to repair, top ic on pic is blown which is why I need to identify the device, the Bruce Abbot link seems most helpful so far, the Seiko S8241A seems plausible but can't locate identical code in datasheet list.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a similar search, on a different board. The SOT23-5 LiPo cell balancing IC in my situation is a ABLIC S-8241 €0,76 https://www.digikey.nl/en/products/detail/ablic-inc/S-8241ABPMC-GBPT2G/1628409. The datasheet calls it a "Battery protection IC for 1-cell pack".
Wiring matches the IC description. The IC print in my case is "R2RL", though.